# Navigating up through an array in PHP

Tags: php

Given the following multi-dimensional array:

```
$family = array(
    "grandfather",
    "grandmother",    
    "father" => array(
        "parents" => array(
            "grandfather",
            "grandmother"
         )
    ),
    "mother" => array(
        "parents" => array(
            "grandfather",
            "grandmother"
         )
    ),
    "son" => array(
        "parents" => array(
            "father",
            "mother"
         )
    ),
    "daughter" => array(
        "parents" => array(
            "father",
            "mother"
         )
    ),
);
```

You can imagine expanding this array to include great-grandparents, great-grandchildren, etc.

I'm sure this is a common and well documented data structure, but I'm not a computer science major and I don't know how to describe or name this particular type of dictionary.

Is there a function built in to PHP that will reliably navigate up this tree, given the name of a "child" node and an "ancestor" node that we are seeking?

For instance:

```
getAncestor($array, $child, $ancestor);
```

I have tried this, and it usually involves recursion with the getAncestor() function nested inside itself, but will sometimes run into "dead ends", in which it will navigate all the way up to the end of one branch.

Comment: Most people would just call this a nested array or multi-dimensional array as you mentioned. As far as I know there is no inbuilt function for this.

Comment: By ancestor, you mean just one level up or multiple?

Comment: Why don't you use xml to describe this? or at least a tree structure? A family is what is called a 'hello world' example for tree structures.

Comment: Arrays are way too generic to have a function for this one in particular.

Comment: I think you should provide an example input and output to clarify which direction is "up". Especially since your example function is called "getAncestor" and you're providing the ancestor as an input to it.

Comment: This was a simplified example, but I'll provide the actual code that is failing to navigate this array.

@DavidCarrington - I'm providing $ancestor as input because I'm telling it what to look for. The 'mission' of the function is to arrive at that value by traversing the array. In the real world use, it's not just trying to find a simple text value that matches $ancestor, and thus the need for the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a more linear approach and instead of nesting everything inside each other you just have a bunch of pointers to all the ancestors in each object. Otherwise this sounds like a recursion-problem to me.

Pointer approach:

```
<?php

$person1 = new PersonObject( 'details' );
$person2 = new PersonObject( 'details' );

$person1->father =& $person2;

?>
```

If your data-set is given like your example you might or might not benefit from translating into this kind system, depending on how many ancestors you need to look up. Also, in my opinion this structure is a lot cleaner =).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I can't imagine how you would add *great-grandparents* without seeing it.  You say recursion is called for, but `$family` has 3 generations of members with only 2 levels of nesting.  If you were to add *great-grandparents* like so (my best guess based on your sample `$family` array), there would still only be 2 levels of nesting.

```
$family = array(
    "great-grandfather",
    "great-grandmother",    
    "grandmother" => array(
        "parents" => array(
            "great-grandmother",
            "great-grandfather"
         )
    ),
    // ...
);
```

Then recursion isn't even necessary.

Though unclear on what *exactly* it's supposed to do based on your description.  It echos out the child and ancestors when a match is found and returns a boolean result.

```
function getAncestor($array, $child, $ancestor)
{
    foreach($array as $_child => $_ancestor) {
        // Bail if child is not a match or ancestor is not array
        if($child != $_child ||
           !is_array($_ancestor) || !count($_ancestor))
            continue;

        // see if cur ancestor is a match for searched ancestor
        if(in_array($ancestor, $_ancestor['parents'])) {
            echo 'Child: ' . $child . PHP_EOL;
            echo 'Ancestors: ' . implode(', ', $_ancestor['parents']) . PHP_EOL;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

getAncestor($family, 'son', 'father');
getAncestor($family, 'father', 'grandmother');
getAncestor($family, 'father', 'mother');
```

Output

> Child: son
>
> Ancestors: father, mother
>
> Child: father
>
> Ancestors: grandfather, grandmother

One other side note on the example `$family`, looks like *father* and *mother* have the same parents!